# Flutter - Hive storage issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I recently learned about the Flutter framework in my university, and I'm currently working on a school project. I don't understand why my data inside the hive box that I am using seems to be erased everytime I quit and re-run the app.

main.dart:

```
void main() async{

  // hive initialization protocol
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(YogaRoutineAdapter());

  yogaExerciseBox = await Hive.openBox<YogaRoutine>('routineBox');

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stress B Gone',
      theme: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

exercise_regime.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mindfulness_app/global_variables.dart';
import 'package:mindfulness_app/yoga_routine.dart';

class ExerciseRegime extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExerciseRegime({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExerciseRegime> createState() => _ExerciseRegimeState();
}

class _ExerciseRegimeState extends State<ExerciseRegime> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<YogaRoutine> yogaRoutine =
        yogaExerciseBox.values.cast<YogaRoutine>().toList();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My regime'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: yogaRoutine.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.fitbit_sharp),
                  title: Text(yogaRoutine[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text(yogaRoutine[index].subtitle),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        yogaExerciseBox.deleteAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.highlight_remove_rounded),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code for insertion:

```
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    YogaRoutine newYogaExercise = YogaRoutine(
                      name: 'Tree Pose',
                      subtitle: 'Your daily dose of energy',
                    );
                    setState(() {
                      yogaExerciseBox.put(
                        'key_${newYogaExercise.name}',
                        newYogaExercise,
                      );
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("Add to routine"),
                ),
              ),
```

I cannot seem to figure out, if there is something wrong with my implementation using hive or does an emulator wipe all data everytime it is closed.